# How to download big video files using WebClient class

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I'm a newbie and I'm developing a windows application. I need to download a video file from my site and that's my issue here. I had designed a custom down-loader, through which I can download images, text files from my site. But I wasn't able download videos from my site. Could anyone please help me out..?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysitename.com/Videos/vid.mp4"), "c:\\movie.mp4");
```

I don't want to download by means of response content dispatch because my client wants me to download through custom browser.. so please let me know solutions from you experts.. thank you

Comment: If it isn't working, then what specific behavior is it exhibiting?

Comment: Hi Babcock, its not any showing error rather it completes download by placing a 0 bytes video file.

Comment: When I tried to access the url in browser.. its throwing 404 error. But the file location is correct. But if I access the images or txt it gets displayed.. so is ter any other way to access the video file.. to make my file downloaded through webclient..

Comment: If accessing the URL in the browser results in a 404, then the file will not be available for download using `WebClient`.

Comment: So how can I download a video file through Webclient.?

Comment: Make the file accessible from the server.

Comment: Do you have web service that streams this video file or is it just a file on the server you are trying to access

Comment: Hmm no its just a mp4 video file. My doubt is that is it really possible to download a video file through webclient?

Comment: Yes its possible to download any file from your server using  WebClient. Its just on how you have the file on the server. Look my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to download a video file with WebClient and it works. My setup is as below:

I have a virtualdirectory(Video) in defaultwebsite (IIS) which has this video file.

I just use the below code to download the video file to C drive:

```
var client = new WebClient();
Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost/Video/wildlife.wmv");
client.DownloadFileAsync(address, @"c:\video.wmv");
```

Also note since you are downloading in Async fashion, wait for about a min for the operation to complete for the full file to be downloaded. Initially it shows 0 bytes but based on the size it takes some time to complete it.

UPDATE: If your server doesnt have the file mime type specified then just add to the collection of mime types that IIS can serve and you can download the file without any problem.

When adding MIME type the following values to be used are (for your scenario):

```
File Extension: .mp4
MIME Type: video/mp4
```

To add mime types in IIS follow these links:

1. [For IIS 4,5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx)
2. [For IIS 6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965)
3. [For IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rajesh.. Now I came to know that specific formats not downloading.. Can you pls try .mp4 files.. Pls let me know whether its downloading for you?

Comment: Yes i did try for mp4 and initially got an error 404. Then i browsed to my virtual directory on IIS and then added a new MIME type for it to be served. Once this was done i could download the file from server without any problems

Comment: Yes, Rajesh. Me too just contacted my server supporter and added the MIME type.. Thank you so much Rajesh. I have some doubts in progressbar sync with downloads too..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a server issue, but if you are doubting your code, you may want to try download sync (I have had some issues in the past downloading async). Another way is to use the WebRequest class. If this server is very remote, try pinging beforehand. I think that you should also check to make sure the file is on the server, and if the file is really big, you should check to see if the file finished uploading.

Comment: I had uploaded a sample (1mb) video file and I'm sure tat its in server. I also tried using both DownloadFile method / DownloadFileAsync method. But its not working. Is it really possible to download a video file through webclient?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the video file? It might help to know, as your problem might be there.